# Wireless settings saved for all users?

Tags: group-policy, wifi

For both Windows 7 and Windows XP the wireless network settings are being saved for all users.

I want to stop this behavior - force all users to enter their own credentials - plus kill any existing items in the shared list. I've found several references for how to address this using the GUI but nothing that I can do via group policy or registry. Anyone know how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows 7 :

To kill saved settings for all users under windows seven clear the contents of the folder **c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces**. This can be achieved with a group policy folder preference.

To allow Windows 7 users to save wireless settings under their own profile publish the key 
**HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\service\WLANSVC\Parameters\WlanAPIPermissions\Add New All User Profiles**. I exported a copy of this key from a laptop with the desired settings and pushed it back out.

In my case this was a string containing the value

```
O:SYG:SYD:(A;;CCRC;;;BU)(A;;CCDCWPSDRCWD;;;BU)(A;;CCRC;;;NO)(A;;CCDCWPSDRCWD;;;NO)(A;;CCRC;;;BA)(A;;CCDCWPSDRCWD;;;BA)(D;;FA;;;WD)
```

This value could probably be tweaked manually to totally stop the use of system stored locations but I didn't bother taking it that far.